# Easiest way to append non-directory component to Python Path?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pathlib

Several SO questions ask how to append a *directory* to a [pathlib.Path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) object. That's *not* this question.

I would like to use a `Path` object a prefix for a series of files in a single directory, like this:

```
2022-01-candidates.csv
2022-01-resumes.zip
2022-02-candidates.csv
2022-02-resumes.zip
```

Ideally, I would construct Path objects for the `2022-01` and `2022-02` components, and then append `-candidates.csv` and `-resumes.zip` to each.

Unfortunately, `Path` appears to only understand appending *subdirectores*, not extensions to existing path names.

The only workaround that I see is something like `p.parent / (p.name + "-candidates.csv")`. Although that's not so bad, it's clumsy and this pattern is common for me.  I wonder whether I'm missing a more streamlined method. (For example, why isn't there a `+` concatenation operator?)

`Path.with_suffix()` requires that the suffix start with a dot, so that doesn't work.

Comment: You just use normal string formatting for this, you don't need a library.

Comment: If it doesn't work for you, you don't have to use it. What you did is probably the best approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, using the division operator always creates a sub-directory, and `with_suffix` is only for extensions. You could use `with_path` to edit the filename:

```py
import pathlib
path = pathlib.Path("2022-01")
path.with_name(f"{path.name}-candidates.csv")
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me. In Python 3.9, the result from your example is `PosixPath('2022-01/-candidates.csv')`

Comment: @Reece you're absolutely right. I've updated the answer to use `with_name` instead of `joinpath`